# PHP SQL Syntax error adding to table 1 with table 2 value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, error-handling

I get an error when running this php code which going to add value to table 1 based on table 2 value where table 3 value equal to 0

MY TABLE

```
------------------------------
id| table 1| table 2 | table 3|
-------------------------------
01| 100    | 10     | 0      |
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "myuser";
    $password = "mypass";
    $dbname = "lol";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE table table1 = table1 + table2 WHERE table 3 = 0";



    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

It said that I have error in my sql syntax

> Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= table1 + table2 WHERE table3 = 0' at line 1

How to achieve this with the correct sql syntax?

Comment: Oh my. You really have a table called table with columns table1 to table3? WHY???!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: @JayBlanchard nope. maybe one with "dont forget the set keyword on update" - Im hoping the table name and columns are aliases strictly for posting here.

Comment: I'm hoping that too @OIS, but you're right - the whole thing is a mess.

Comment: I think we're a little lost in the syntax because it's hard to tell if you're confusing columns and tables or something entirely different. See if you can take a step back from the sample names and use realistic column / table names so people can understand what you're doing a bit better. Then explain it with more of a straight-forward story: "I need to add the sale_discount and promotion_discount columns on table sales and then..."

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the table and field names are aliases.  Try this...

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `table 1` = `table 1` + `table 2` WHERE `table 3` = 0";
```

You need `SET` for an `UPDATE` statement, and fields or tables with spaces in the names need to be surrounded by the backtick character.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `SET` directive and your column names do not match those in your query, for which you'd have to use back ticks -

```
 $sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `table 1` = `table 1` + `table 2` WHERE `table 3` = 0";
```

You really should learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)